# Convert all POSIXct/POSIXlt columns to Date

Tags: r, date, posixct

I am trying to load multiple dataframes in R and all databases got at least one column (dateCreated) in POSIXct format. Some dataframes got multiple POSIXct columns. I want to convert all POSIXct columns to dates.

```
a<-sapply(i, is.POSIXct)
i[a]<-lapply(i[a], as.Date)
```

I don't find a function like is.POSIXct implemented yet. Any help?

Comment: You can define `is.POSIXct<-function(x) inherits(x,"POSIXct")`

Comment: Perfect, worked like charm.

Comment: `lubridate` has `is.POSIXct`, but it's just `is(x, "POSIXct")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
i[] <- lapply(i, function(x) if(inherits(x, "POSIXct")) as.Date(x) else x)
```

Notice how we take advantage of `i[]` to skip the first `sapply`.